# For each set of keywords in one table, find all matching hits in a second table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, search

Disclaimer: I'm using MySQL with 2 tables. So far I've found solutions to my issue when individual groups are queried one at a time using IN() but nothing that allows me to do the whole table at once without looping over multiple queries.

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE WordGroups (
  wgId int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  groupId int NOT NULL,
  word varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (wgId)
);
```

Which keeps track of groups of keywords, word to groupId, and

```
CREATE TABLE ArticleWords (
  awId int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  articleId int NOT NULL,
  word varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (awId)
);
```

which keeps track of the key words within an article.

I am attempting to build a single query which can take the groups of words, and return for each group all articles which contain AT LEAST all of those words.

I realize if I look for one group at a time in a single query this is very simple, however I can't seem to figure out how to make a single query result in the set of all matching subsets.

For example imagine that the two tables have the following data:

**WordGroups**

```
groupId   |  word
-----------------
1         |  B
1         |  A
2         |  C
2         |  E
3         |  F
```

**ArticleWords**

```
articleId |  word
-----------------
1         |  A
1         |  C
1         |  B
2         |  C
3         |  A
3         |  B
3         |  F
4         |  C
4         |  E
4         |  F
```

The resulting query would return:

```
groupId | articleId
1       | 1
1       | 3
2       | 4
3       | 3
3       | 4
```

Since those articles contain at least all the words from those groups.

I've attempted an intersection of the two tables using an inner join but that matches incomplete groups of words resulting in the row:

```
groupId | articleId
2       | 2
```

Showing up in the result all because Article 2 contains the word "C". I'm open to ideas as I've dabbled in less serious MySQL but this has been eluding me all week.

Any help is much appreciated. I'm at the point where I'm wondering if I'm trying to make SQL do something it isn't meant to do. I have a very long query which works for WordGroups up to 6 words but it is very exact and not scalable, this query would need to work for any size WordGroup to be feasible.

Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one method, uses `group_concat()` for the comparison:

```
select wg.groupId, aw.articleId
from articlewords aw join
     wordgroups wg
     on wg.word = aw.word join
     (select wg.groupId, group_concat(wg.word order by word) as words
      from word_groups wg
      group by wg.groupId
     ) wgw
     on wgw.groupId = wg.groupid
group by aw.articleid, wgw.words
having group_concat(aw.word order by aw.word) = wgw.words;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5592d1/17) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: I tried something like this where I wanted to join the results of two group_concats that were ordered the same (alphabetically for example). However I can't seem to get the syntax to work. I tried running your above query but it too has a syntax error: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5592d1/4

Comment: I also realized, that even if I could compare the two I'd need to test all permutations and exclusions because I don't just want exact matches, I want matches where AT LEAST all words are in that article, the article could still have other words as well.

Comment: @DevByTradeAndLove . . . Fixes a bunch of small mishaps in the query.  It works.

Comment: @Gorgon Linoff this did the trick! It's the having that I totally missed. Brilliant, thank you for the help!